# A Relation between Dirichlet L functions for Quadratic Character and Gauss sums

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, characters, gauss-sums

This is problem 8 of Chapter 16 in the book A Classical Approach to Modern Number Theory by Ireland and Rosen.

Let $g(\chi)$ be the classical Gauss sum : $\sum_{x = 1}^{p-1} \chi(x) \zeta^{x} $, $\chi$ the Legendre symbol. $\zeta = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{p} }$.

Define $P = \prod (1 - \zeta ^n)(1 - \zeta ^{r})^{-1}$ where $r, n$ run respectively over the nonsquares and squares mod p.

Show $$P = e^{g(\chi) L(1, \chi)} $$

where $L(s, \chi)$ is the Dirichlet $L$ function for the unique non-trivial Quadratic character mod $p$ (a prime).

This exercise can be used to compute $L$ explcitly at $1$.

I am trying to express $g(\chi) L (1, \chi)$ in terms of logarithms but I unable to.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're unable to? What goes wrong? What are you trying?

Comment: $\chi(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{p-1} c_k e^{2i\pi nk/p}$ (discrete Fourier transform), $ L(1,\chi) = -\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} c_k \log(1-e^{2i\pi nk/p})$. It remains to investigate the $c_k$.

Comment: @prets I meant that I think $g(\chi) L(1, \chi)$ should be written in terms of log but I am stuck. So, basically I meant I am stuck.

Comment: @reuns, Thank you. Now I get it. I did not think of first trying to determine $L$ first since the next problem in the book asks to find $L(1, \chi)$ using this problem.

Comment: @reuns, So, $c_k = \frac{1}{p} \sum_{t = 1}^{p-1} \chi(t) e^{\frac{-2 \pi t k}{p}} = \chi(-k)g(\chi)$. Now we make two cases $p \equiv 1 \text{mod} 4$ or $\ \equiv -1 \text{mod} 4$.  In the first case $g(\chi) = \sqrt{p}$ and $\chi(-k) = \chi(k)$ and so we get $ L(1, \chi) g(\chi) = \sum \chi(k)(log (1 - e^{\frac{i2 \pi}{p} }))$  and so on.